# Running Selenium test in Tomcat on remote server gives "Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays"

Tags: linux, selenium, tomcat, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to execute a Selenium Test with WebDriver on a remote server but it fails with the message:

```
1503556834416   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.18.0
1503556834420   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:13167
1503556834659   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser /usr/bin/firefox with args ["-marionette"]
Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays
```

The test is part of a Spring Boot webapp and is hosted in a Tomcat 8.5.20. The test execution is triggered by calling a url link of the Spring Boot webapp.
As Browser Firefox with geckodriver is used and this is the code which leads to the error:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/opt/geckodriver");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
```

The server has a Debian 8 OS with LXDE as desktop environment.
No matter how i call this webapp link:

- ssh login and using lynx on remote server
- executing tightvncserver :1 on remote server, using a remote desktop client from my local machine and just calling this link in the firefox installed on the remote server
- just calling the remote url from my local machine

... im getting always the **GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays**
error.

In my local environment (the only difference regards the test is a different Linux OS; everthing else like versions of Tomcat, webapp, geckodriver, ... are the same ) this test is executed without any problems. This is the log snippet:

```
1503556181640   geckodriver     INFO    geckodriver 0.18.0
1503556181643   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:18039
1503556181805   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox with args ["-marionette"]
1503556182440   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 44917
08:29:43.198 [Forwarding newSession on session null to remote] INFO  org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake - Detected dialect: W3C
... and now the test is executed ...
```

I suppose its connected with the configuration of the remote server and has nothing to do with Selenium but im having no idea what to do next...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Xvfb was the key...

So i removed the LXDE as it was not longer needed (and i thougth i need a desktop for selenium) and started tomcat with xvfb-run.
After i started xvfb (with port 99) and exported the display variable.

Example (using full path as they are used in systemd boot scripts):

```
export DISPLAY=:99

/usr/bin/xvfb-run /opt/tomcat-latest/bin/startup.sh

/usr/bin/Xvfb :99 &
```